# extjs 2.3 application using MVC Architecture

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs2

Iam trying to implement my applicaion in ext js 2.3 using mvc architecture.

Can someone suggest me the classes available in ext 2.3 version to implement MVC.

Any links to extjs 2.3 tutorials will be highly useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extjs 5 is in market with lot of feature , why you are opting for 2.3

Comment: the project iam working with is already implemented long time back in 2.3. Now iam trying to convert it into MVC format.. I checked with new versions and there are many features available to implement mvc. But i dint find any way to implement it in 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

MVC has never been implemented in Ext 2.3, as far as I know. I also think that it is not worth the effort as 2.3 is three versions back and it is really outdated today.

If you have a motivation and resources to upgrade the existing app then opt to update the app to Ext 5.x. It would be much better spent development time.

Answer (score 0):

In Extjs4.x, the MVC appears for the first time. So it can't be used in previous versions. It becomes mvvm in Extjs5.x. I recommend you to learn Extjs4.x or Extjs5.x.